# The Script Task Uses Version 15.0 that is not supported in the release of integration services

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

My team is planning to move from SQL Server 2014 to 2016. Currently, SSIS package is created in VS 2013 and deployed on SQL Server 2014. For testing i tried to deploy the package in SSMS 17.3 (Integration services 13.0). The package is successfully deployed but when i try to validate the package, the get the following error:

[image]

After reading some solutions on the internet, I deployed the package from the following path:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn
```

The package was successfully validated (without modifying ispac file). As per my understanding, the script task is created with VSTA major version 15 in VS 2017. I tried to open the solution in VS 2015 and rebuilt the solution with SQL server 2017 as target server. Before deploying the package on SSMS 17.3, I made sure that the dtsx file contains 15 VSTA major version.

After verifying, i deployed the package on SSMS 17.3 which is using the following path:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn
```

I validated the package but i got the same error. As per my understanding, if i build the solution by selecting SQL server 2017 as target version, it should be successfully validated. How can i resolve this issue if i want to use SSMS 17.3 for deployment?

Comment: why selecting `SQL server 2017` while you are updating to `sql server 2016`??!!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that only sql server 2017 target version is supported on SSMS 17.3.  I basically want to deploy SSIS 2014 ispac to 2016. SSMS 17.3 is installed with SQL SERVER 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a while on this issue, it looks like this is a common issue of SSMS 17.x you must install 16.x versions to avoid this error or deploy with SQL Server 2016 deployment tools *(`Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn`)* as you mentioned:

For more information, read the discussions below, they contains very helpful

- [SSMS 17.3 and VS 2015 deployment issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70d7f86d-8de6-42bc-86fb-a9347b5e6010/ssms-173-and-vs-2015-deployment-issue?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Difference between .ispac and SSDT deploy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8c45962d-ac7b-4e2c-a4f6-c93479b57908/differnece-between-ispac-and-ssdt-deploy?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: confirming: its bug in SSMS 17.X, when deploying ispac through SSMS to server < 2016.
No such problems with SSMS 18.3.1.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the Target Server Version was set to 2017. I updated it to 2016 and it worked.

[image]